# How to insert Excel formula to cell in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, excel-formula, ssrs-2008-r2

There is RDL report template for SQL Server Reporting Services.
I need to set value for cell in table in the report template which must be calculated from other values in the report.
When the report is exported to Excel file I need to see the Excel formula in that cell.

Example:

1) Sample report template with three columns table. First cell must be sum of second and third:
[image: step 1]

2) I set expression for first column to reproduce excel formula in output report:

[image: step 2]

3) When report was exported to Excel file I see raw text of formula in cell:
[image: step 3]
4) But when I click on value in excel formula input cell converted to right value:
[image: step 4]

Comment: SSRS is not Excel so you can't use Excel cell references.

Comment: @DavidG I know, but I need to use any workaround to implement cell references. So Excel correctly interpreted this formula, but after I click on cell value.

Comment: You can use SSRS expressions but they will export as values, not formulas when shown in Excel.

Comment: @DavidG The Customer requirement is Formula, not formatted value, unfortunately.

Comment: Then what you are asking for is not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excel Formulas support has ended since SSRS 2008 (see [Breaking Changes in SQL Server Reporting Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143380%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)).

> **No Formula Support in Excel**
>
> In earlier versions of Reporting Services, there was limited support
>   for translating expressions in RDL to Microsoft Excel formulas. In
>   this release, when you export a report to Excel, RDL expressions are
>   not translated to Excel formulas.

If you really need to have the formulas in the excel file and can't use SSRS 2005, you could do the following workaround:

- Append an extra `'` before every formula (ex: `="'=C3+B3"`) in your report
- Open the exported excel file
- Do a find and replace to remove the leading `'`

But it will not suit every cases...

Comment: I could not make the replacement the character ' but if I set value to ="SOME_KEY_STRING=C3+B3", I successfully replaced "SOME_KEY_STRING=" to "=" and then formulas are working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to export Excel formulas from SQL Server Reporting Services. The only thing you can do is use standard SSRS expressions but these will export as values in Excel (and any other export format.)