# Exporting formulas to excel from ssrs 2008R2

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I am aware that in 2008 the method of exporting formula to excel was downgraded [see here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ddf2f19d-3f70-4bb0-a035-00709ffee2f9/excel-formulas-in-ssrs-2008?forum=sqlreportingservices).

But I have seen a workaround for a static formula where the same formula is required (see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584986/ssrs-report-export-to-excel-formulas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000303/how-to-insert-excel-formula-to-cell-in-report-builder-3-0)). However I have the case where I need a relative formula when I export to excel. Is there a newer solution out there does anyone know?

This is my workings so far
The result I am after is cell `(T,r3) = cell (R,r3)-cell(O,r3)` and then `cell (T,r4) = cell (R,r4)-cell(O,r4)` and so on in excel I would expect to see
in cell `T3 the formula =R3-O3`
and cell `T4 the formula =R4-O4`

```
      O!P!Q!R !S!T!
r3  1    5   N   5           4  
r4  3    5   N   10          7
```

(Sorry I can not get the table to line up)

my ssrs expression is

```
="=R"+cstr(RowNumber("DataSet1")+2)+"-O"+cstr(RowNumber("DataSet1")+2)
```

where DataSet1 is what my ssrs tablix is based on and the +2 element is to offset to allow how the titles of the report and the table move the first row of data down the excel sheet.

The output is achieve in the cells when exported to excel is the formula as text in the cell content and if I click into the cell and press backspace and return the formula works. It appears that some white space is being exported or excel just treats every thing as text on the import routine

I can of course use and find and replace on this statement in excel

`="=R"+cstr(RowNumber("DataSet1")+2)+"-O"+cstr(RowNumber("DataSet1")+2)`  as suggested but was trying to be more elegant

I do not suppose you can export some code to run in excel as vba to do the find and replace function at a button press for the user?

Has anyone any suggestions - thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not supported the workaround is tedious. For each cell that has a formula you can:

1. Select the cell
2. Click in the formula bar
3. Press Enter

This causes Excel to evaluate the string as a formula and replaces the text with the value it represents.

You can't export VBA from SSRS but you could paste in your own VBA after export and run it to accomplish the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

I use **SSIS** to populate an Excel report template with data and formulas.

I had too many formulas to have to go into the worksheets and updated them manually.

In a script task, I use VB to calculate the formula and populate it in a sheet as well as underline the appropriate line:

```
    ExcelFormula = "=SUM(" & SumColumn & "45:" & SumColumn & Row.ToString & ")"

    Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column - 1).Formula = ExcelFormula
    Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column - 1).BORDERS(9).Weight = 2
    Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column).BORDERS(9).Weight = 2
```

It's a bit more work initially but once you get it set up to work with one cell, the rest are relatively easy.